# DirectoryChooser - multiple directories

Tags: directory, javafx, filechooser

JavaFX - Is it possible to choose multiple directories at once with DirectoryChooser?

Or is there any way how to do this without DirectoryChooser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API to choose multiple directories with the JavaFX 2.2 [DirectoryChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/DirectoryChooser.html).

Related JavaFX issue tracker issue:

[RT-28443 There is no api in Directory chooser for selecting multiple directories.](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-28443)